# Akka actor cardinality

Tags: akka, actor, cardinality

After reading most of the Akka docs, I still don't understand something fairly fundamental to Akka: actor cardinality.

Meaning, if I have a particular actor, say `FizzActor`, does Akka ever *only* create 1 instance of it, or does it spawn n-instances of it as needed? If it can spawn multiple instances of an actor class, then is this configurable (if so how/where?), or does Akka alone determine how many instances to create? Does stopping/restarting/resuming this actor class perform the action on all instances of the actor or just the one child instance? Can I assume that Akka coordinates state changes across all `FizzActor` instances, so that each time I get an `ActorRef` to it, I see a consistent state?

None of these seem to be covered in the docs!

Answer (score 2):

Akka's primary philosophy is "no magic", i.e. if you create *an actor* that's what happens - one Actor is created. Refer to the docs on [Creating Actors with Props](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.11/scala/actors.html#Creating_Actors_with_Props) for a deeper explanation.

The one case where Akka takes care of starting multiple Actors in your stead is  [Pool Routers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html), which as explained in the docs:

> Pool - The router creates routees as child actors and removes them from the router if they terminate

Comment: Thanks @Konrad (+1) - then is it even *possible* to create multiple instances of the same actor class, if so, how/where in the config/code? Also, if so, what about my other questions (does stopping the actor stop all instances or just the one? will Akka coordinate state change across all instances or not)? Thanks again so much!

Comment: Actors are like people – autonomous :-) `context.stop(self)` stops the one Actor, yourself - any stopping of other Actors requires telling them to stop (`juliet ! PoisonPill`) or the parent actor stopping its children, please read the docs on Supervision: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html